# Find max value of a column and result the value corresponding to the row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of data in a table of 5 rows and 2 columns. First column has numbers and a second column has values for the respective row in the first column.

I am trying to choose the maximum number in the first column that has the least value in the corresponding row in the second column and create a new table with only values up to the maximum number in the first column and corresponding value in the second column.

Comment: An example would be useful here

Comment: Value Count0
0 242
1 8
2 6
3 0
4 1
5 0

Comment: Updating your original post would make it easier to read. Plus your expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't this function just be the identity function...?

Comment: my question is answered. Do I need to update my questions clearly

Comment: It's better to update, may be it helps someone else, who has same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are looking for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [0,1,2,3,4],'col2': [1,24,1,0,1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame (d, columns = ['col1','col2']) 
index=df[df['col2'].eq(df['col2'].min())]['col1'].idxmax()
df2=df.loc[0:index]
df2
```

---

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0      0       1
1      1      24
2      2       1
3      3       0
```

**Additionaly to select the min>0:**

```
index=df[df['col2'].eq(df.loc[df['col2']>0,'col2'].min())]
```

note: the number of rows is not important in this problem

Comment: yes, this is what I am expecting. I tried with the code, but I am getting error "dtype: int64' is an invalid key" at this line
 df2=df.loc[0:index]

Comment: Try :`df2=df.reset_index(drop=True).loc[0:index]`

Comment: can you show me an example of your dataframe? i want help you

Comment: d = {'col1':[0,1,2,3,4], 'col2':[1,24,1,0,1]}    
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['col1','col2'])     
df     
index=df.loc[df[df['col2'].eq(df['col2'].min())]['col1'].idxmax()]     
df2=df.reset_index(drop=True).loc[0:index]     
df2

Comment: ok, i update the new code! see it!

Comment: is it work for you?

Comment: It throws me a error                                                                               
TypeError: 'col1    3   
col2    0
Name: 3, dtype: int64' is an invalid key

Comment: do you copy and paste my code?

Comment: yes, I copied your code. it's now working. I am not sure why it did not work earlier. just one more question. if I want to choose the least number as number>0, would you give me any suggestions?

Comment: the row that contains the smallest number greater than 0?

Comment: exactly . I want to find max number in 'col1' and pick the corresponding row in 'col2' that has smallest number greater than 0. I have to include condition for the min() value

Comment: You can use: `index=df[df['col2'].eq(df.loc[df['col2']>0,'col2'].min())]['col1'].idxmax()` , the min of col2 would be 1 and the max of column 2 =4

Comment: you nailed it! thanks

Comment: okey accept my answer please!